# Why $Q(π)$ is not a splitting field over $Q(π^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

I have seen this problem in Algebra textbook by Fraleigh.

But I couldn't find any explanation.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: It is a splitting field.

Comment: Oh... I think the solution is wrong... thank you